# Visual Studio built MSI no longer showing unistall/remove option from Add Remove Programs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

This MSI installer I created from Visual Studio used to work perfectly but now something has changed and when I install it, and then go to uninstall from Windows Add/Remove Programs I see no option to remove.

It looks like:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/09b9gn5b4

No remove button, so I've been using msicuu.exe to force uninstall.

But really I want to get to the bottom of why this isn't working and get the uninstall option back in there.

Built using Visual Studio 2010 with TargetPlatform x64, .Net 4.0 on my Windows XP 32bit dev machine. Installed on Windows Server 2003 x64. Used to work fine, for some reason no longer.

Answer (score 0):

Check that [`ARPNOREMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367591(v=vs.85).aspx) is not set in your installation package. Setting this property prevents Remove functionality in Add/Remove Programs Control Panel.

Comment: Is this something I have inadvertently done in Visual Studio 2010? I can't seem to find where this property is to undo it. I definitely have not done any other custom editing of this MSI or other custom installation switches when using it.

Comment: @m3ntat, I don't know. You can use Orca from SDK to examine the Properties table in your resulting package. Alternatively you can decompile MSI package with WiX and search .wsx file for ARPNOREMOVE. If it's there, you need to remove it.

Comment: For a package created with Visual Studio most likely the installer information got corrupted. Did you try testing the package on a clean machine?